# I am using WFFM 8.2 with SXA. While creating custom fields, I am not able to see the properties in the Form designer

Tags: wffm, sxa

This is the code behind.

```
namespace web.insurance.Models
{
    public class SingleLineTextWithPlaceholderField : Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.Fields.SingleLineTextField
    {
        [Default Value("")]
        public string  PlaceholderText { get; set; }
        public SingleLineTextWithPlaceholderField(Item item) : base()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of Form designer.
[image: I want to have a custom field. I added above class and a cshtml file as a view. But the property **PLaceholdertext** is not showing in the Form Designer as mentioned in the image.]

Comment: [link]https://soen.ghost.io/creating-a-custom-field-type-in-wffm-for-sitecore/

Comment: I have referred above link to create the Custom field.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell the form editor that you want that field to be editable by an attribute, e.g. the line

> [VisualFieldType(typeof(EditField))]

before

> public string  PlaceholderText { get; set; }

should do the trick.

In case Visual studio can't resolve the namespace try adding

> using Sitecore.Form.Core.Attributes;

See e.g. https://github.com/islaytitans/FileUploadValidator/blob/master/JonathanRobbins.FileUploadValidator/Webforms/Controls/SecureFileUpload.cs for an example of fields with different editable properties.